# Codeigniter set_value undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code in the CI controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $data['category'] = $this->categories_model->get_categories($id);
            $this->load->view("templates/admin_header", $data);
            $this->load->view("categories/edit", $data);
            $this->load->view("templates/admin_footer", $data); 
        }
        else
        {
            $array = array('id'=>$id, 'category_name' => $this->input->post('category_name'));

            $this->categories_model->update($array);
            $this->load->view("templates/admin_header");
            $this->load->view("categories/edit");
            $this->load->view("templates/admin_footer");
        }
```

And in the view I have this:

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="category_name" value="<?php echo set_value('category_name', $category['category_name']); ?>"/>
```

When I load the view for the first time, it gets the category_name value from the database and it displays it in the input field. But when I post the form, it updates the database, but when the view loads after the post, it shows me this error:

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: category

and it breaks the html of the input field.

Comment: because you send $category into your view only in the case the form is not validate. Put $data['category'].. outside the condition.

Comment: I know that, but in that case I would query the database even if I post the form. I wanted in that case to display the value from the post. It works fine if it is outside the condition...

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    $array = array('id'=>$id, 'category_name' => $this->input->post('category_name'));

    $this->categories_model->update($array);        
}

$data['category'] = $this->categories_model->get_categories($id);  

$this->load->view("templates/admin_header", $data);
$this->load->view("categories/edit");
$this->load->view("templates/admin_footer");
```